# Reduce the spacing between the icons when browser shrinks

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to design a nav-bar using flex-box. I have three `div` and whenever the browser shrinks, I want to reduce the spacing between the icons inside `header__center`class.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.header__left>img {
  height: 40px;
}

.header__center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header__right {
  display: flex;
}

.header__info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.header__info>span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Free_logo.svg/600px-Free_logo.svg.png" />

  </div>
  <div class="header__center d-none d-xl-flex d-md-flex">
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <div class="header__info d-none d-xl-flex">
      <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg"></i>
      <span class="header__info__name">Aakash</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to still place those icons in the center and reduce the spacing? or is there any easy way to handle using the `bootstrap 4` classes?

And the div is only visible in `xl` `md` devices.

Comment: Use `vw` instead of `px` for padding. vw stands for view width which is the measure according to the screen width so it will automatically adjust. In your case try 2vw instead of 30px padding left and right

Comment: that worked...but is this the most appropriate way?

Comment: Yeah if you want the sizes to be dynamic, either use percentage or vw instead of pixels

Comment: You can also try using vmin or vmax : https://css-tricks.com/simple-little-use-case-vmin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measure your `padding` property in units of `vw`, not `px`.

This represents a fraction of the viewport/window/tab width.